# I have two different data files in my S3 bucket. How do I load them both to the correct tables?

Tags: aws-glue

Completely new to AWS Glue and Python, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have two different file formats arriving into a single S3 bucket, and all I need to do is load them into two different SQL tables in my DB, depending on some wildcards in the filename. This should be relatively simple, but I'm not convinced I'm going in the right direction, and I'm struggling to find many examples on-line

I can set up two separate loaders using the front end without too many issues, but I need to set these up as a single job. Currently, Glue won't differentiate between the two file types, and will load them both into the same table, depending on which job is running

Does anyone have an example Python Script that does this?

I have been working with the two Python scripts that Glue has created, and attempted to combine them into one. I've done this by adding a filename to my dynamic frame, then used a bit of spark SQL to send this data into two different dataframes. I can them process these separately by converting the dataframes back into a dynamic frame, and letting the glue script run as normal.

This works fine for the first dataframe, and almost works for the second file too, but only a few fields are being loaded, and they are incorrectly mapped, as they are inheriting the definition of the first file when the dynamic frame is created. However, I can't see how I can query the filename any earlier in the script

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "testDBname", table_name = "Customers", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

## Convert to Dataframe
dsdataframe=datasource0.toDF();

## Add filename
dsdataframe=dsdataframe.withColumn("sourcetable", input_file_name()) ;
dsdataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("sourcedata")

## Put Customer data into one dataframe
CustomerDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sourcedata where upper(sourcetable) like '%CUSTOMERS%'")

## Put Transaction data into another dataframe
TransactionsDF = spark.sql("select * FROM sourcedata where upper(sourcetable) like '%TRANSACTIONS%'")

## Convert Customer Dataframe back into Dynamic Frame
datasource0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(CustomerDF, glueContext,"datasource0");

...rest of script 1 here....

## Convert Transactions Dataframe back into Dynamic Frame
datasource0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(TransactionsDF, glueContext,"datasource0");

...rest of script 2 here....
```

Comment: The data from both the sources are getting written to the same directory in the same bucket? If yes, then you should first write them in different directories(path) even if in the same bucket.

Comment: Then you can create 2 different tables in glue catalog, either through aws glue crawler or aws Athena.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a pre-existing system that I'm upgrading to use Glue, and I've not the option of getting the files sent over in different folders.

Comment: What are the file formats?

Comment: Both are CSV files, one with about 20 fields containing personal information (name, address, emails, telephone etc). The other contains a dozen fields relating to transnational information (order number, product line, quantity etc)

Comment: glue catalogue cannot differentiate tables based on files. It accepts path till the base folder. Then, either you can create external table manually through Athena or let Glue Crawler do it for you. Since the schema is different for 2 different files, it is not possible to create 2 different tables.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Athena and/or Glue catalogue does not support creating tables on same path which contains files with different schema.

AWS documentation states following :

> Athena reads all files in an Amazon S3 location you specify in the
>   CREATE TABLE statement, and cannot ignore any files included in the
>   prefix. When you create tables, include in the Amazon S3 path only the
>   files you want Athena to read. Use AWS Lambda functions to scan files
>   in the source location, remove any empty files, and move unneeded
>   files to another location.

Reference : [Table location in athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html)

For your use case, you will need to store files with different schema in two different directories on S3 (bucket can be same) and create different external tables on both the paths.

To create external tables you can either use AWS Athena or AWS Glue Crawler. Both will update the table meta information in glue catalog which can be later on used in glue etl jobs.

Comment: Not really the answer I was hoping for, but thank you for taking the time to respond

Comment: You are welcome . There is no other possible way while working with S3/Athena/Glue